# Toggling divs to slide at certain times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/6bt70uhj/9/

```
 $('#name-a').click(function() {
 $('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
 window.setTimeout(function (){$('#bio-line-2').slideToggle( "slow"  );      }, 300);
```

When clicking the link the first lines slides in from the left, and then when that is finished the second line slides in from the top. When it slides back to be hidden, the first line slides aways before the second line does.

How can I change it so the second line slides away before the first line slides away?

Comment: Take a look at [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap), with it you can create complex animations (and play them in reverse) much easier than with jQuery.

Comment: By using [velocity.js `.reverse()`](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#reverse) you'll kill two flys with one hit. Velocity.js is much more performant than jquerys `.animate()` and its easy to use, just include source and change `animate()` to `velocity()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#name-a').click(function () {
    if ($('#bio-line-1').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#bio-line-1').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#bio-line-2').slideToggle("slow");
        }, 300);
    }
    else {
        $('#bio-line-2').slideToggle("slow");

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#bio-line-1').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6bt70uhj/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$('#name-a').click(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#bio-line-2').slideToggle("slow", function () {

            $('#bio-line-1').animate({
                width: 'toggle'
            });
        });
    }, 300);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6bt70uhj/11/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```js
var $l2 = $('#bio-line-2'),
  $l1 = $('#bio-line-1');
var $a = $('#name-a').click(function() {
  $a.toggleClass('visible');
  var visible = $a.hasClass('visible'),
    $f = visible ? $l1 : $l2,
    $s = visible ? $l2 : $l1;

  $f.animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  });
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $s.slideToggle("slow");
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
#name-a {
  left: 38px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 38px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#bio-line-1 {
  left: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 35px;
  width: 633px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#bio-line-1 p {
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  width: 552px;
}
#bio-line-2 {
  left: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 38px;
  width: 633px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#bio-line-2 p {
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  width: 552px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name-a">
  <a href="#">John Love</a>
</div>
<div id="bio-line-1" class="hidden">
  <p>holds a Master's Degree from the University of the Arts</p>
</div>
<div id="bio-line-2" class="hidden">
  <p>London and currently works in London.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#name-a').click(function() {
    if($("#bio-line-2").is(":visible")){
        window.setTimeout(function (){
            $('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        }, 300);
        $('#bio-line-2').slideToggle( "slow" ); 
    }
    else{
        window.setTimeout(function (){
            $('#bio-line-2').slideToggle( "slow" ); 
        }, 300);
        $('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this. I would also not use a `setTimeout` as it is not a reliable way to trigger consecutive animations. The timer can trigger at different times depending on what is happening in the UI thread and therefore ruining the effect you are trying to create. You should use the [animate success callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) of each animation in order to trigger the next one at the exact right time.

http://jsfiddle.net/6bt70uhj/23/

```
var $line1 = $('#bio-line-1'),
    $line2 = $('#bio-line-2');

$('#name-a').click(function() {
    if (!$line1.is(":visible")) {
        $line1.animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 300, function () {
            $line2.slideToggle("slow");
        });
    } else {
        $line2.slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $line1.animate({
                width: 'toggle'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i have made some condition that while showing the lines, line number 1   will appear first and then line number 2 will appear. and while hiding lines, line number 2 will hide first and then line number 1 will hide... i think this is what you trying
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6bt70uhj/21/) is fiddle link

Thank You